# Test if file exists in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I can use Test-Path to check whether the file name entered exists, but I'd like to avoid producing a system error if the user hits `RETURN` and the input string is blank.  I thought the `-ErrorAction` Common Parameter would do the trick, but this:

```
$configFile = Read-Host "Please specify a config. file: "
$checkfile = Test-Path $configFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

still produces:

```
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Scripts\testparm2.ps1:19 char:31
+         $checkfile = Test-Path <<<<  $configFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

Do I have to check that the string isn't blank or NULL explicitly?

I'm using PowerShell v2.0

Comment: if you check Ansgar Wiechers answer... your code returns $true when you pass a 0

Comment: Just to avoid confusing innocent bystanders: 0 and null are different values with different meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$checkfile = if ("$configFile") {
               Test-Path -LiteralPath $configFile
             } else {
               $false
             }
```

The double quotes prevent false negatives, e.g. in case you want to test for the existence of a folder named `0`.

Another option would be to set `$ErrorActionPreference`. However, in that case you need to cast the result of `Test-Path` to a boolean value, because although the exception is suppressed the cmdlet still doesn't return a result. Casting that `$null` "return value" to `bool` produces `$false`.

```
$oldEAP = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$checkfile = [bool](Test-Path -LiteralPath $configFile)

$ErrorActionPreference = $oldEAP
```

Comment: Interesting "false negative" when passing 0 as parameter

Comment: @cad A numeric value of 0 would be interpreted as `$false` whereas a string `"0"` wouldn't (because it's not empty). See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) for details.

Comment: @cad @Ansgar Wiechers,  Thanks to both of you.  Can you explain why the `-ErrorAction` clause didn't work?

Comment: It should... I don't know why.

Comment: @rojomoke I would suspect that the parameter binding errors are not covered by the error action (since `-ErrorAction` is a parameter too). You can set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you have to check explicitly for string null or empty:

```
$configFile = Read-Host "Please specify a config. file: "
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($configFile))
{
    $checkfile = $false
}
else 
{
    $checkfile = Test-Path $configFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Or use try/catch:

```
$configFile = Read-Host "Please specify a config. file: "
if ( $(Try { Test-Path $configFile.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) 
{
   $checkfile = $true
}
else 
{
   $checkfile = $false
}
```